# show/hide options show option and remove previous select with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The selector function works great on desktop however when on native iphone dropdown you have to deselect option in order to see the next select. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get around this with show and hide jQuery. Basically if select next option remove previous and show one at a time?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#storeselector').change(function() {
    $('.store-hide').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.store-right {
  float: right;
}

.i-store {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: inherit;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 4%;
}

.store-img {
  max-width: 1150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.store-hide {
  display: none;
}

.store-block {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="storeselector" tabindex="2" multiple size="3">
  <option value="level-lg">
    Lower Ground
  </option>
  <option value="level-g">
    Ground Floor
  </option>
  <option value="level-one">
    Level 1
  </option>

</select>

<div id="level-lg" class="store-hide store-block" style="display: block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="i-store">
                                LG
                            </span>
    <img class="store-img" src="https://www.ctshirts.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dw468e879c/UK/SS18/Book6/hp-recs1_UK.jpg" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="level-g" class="store-hide store-block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="i-store">
                                G
                            </span>
    <img class="store-img" src="https://www.ctshirts.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dwc0f6b72a/UK/SS18/Book6/hp-recs2_UK.jpg" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="level-one" class="store-hide store-block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="i-store">
                                1
                            </span>
    <img class="store-img" src="https://www.ctshirts.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dwe06b0b29/UK/SS18/Book6/hp-recs3_UK.jpg" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hcoh6yL9/

Comment: Is it an option to remove the `multiple` attribute in the `select`?